# How do I restore the GPU after docker?

Tags: windows, gpu, nvidia, docker-desktop

I have a project in which a separate docker container is allocated

```yaml
gpt-service:
    build:
      context: /gpt
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./gpt:/app
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [ gpu ]
```

Today, for the first time in all my use, the screen just went dark, while all the sounds remained and I couldn't do anything.

Next, I restarted the computer, but it did not give any result.
I tried to turn everything on to the motherboard, and saw the image, then I tried to figure out what the problem was with the video card, a blue screen came out, after which the problem was solved.

Windows 11, graphics processor - RTX 4080

The first time I didn't understand what the problem was, because I came across it not the second time by downloading a new docker compose, but not the time when no blue crane was followed.

I tried various ways to configure work with the GPU, such as: `sfc/scannow`, recovery system, in test mode, when my GPU was turned off, I deleted it and thought I assigned it, but now it's not there.

I set everything up in the bios by default, suggested `bcdedit /set pciexpress forcedisable`, `dism online cleanup-restore` the health image, nothing special.

I tried downloading drivers from nvidia, but I don't understand that the drivers are not available.

Comment: I don't follow where the problem is. But if the video card is misbehaving you can try the Windows shortcut to restart to GPU driver: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Win`+`B`